# Bind embedded type when form is submitted

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have created 2 types, `Car` and `Engine`

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [...]
    public virtual Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public EngineType EngineType { get; set; }
    public Aspiration Aspiration { get; set; }
    public double OilSumpCapacity { get; set; }
}
```

I've setup relation between them:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(e =>
        {
            e.OwnsOne(e => e.Engine);
            e.HasMany(e => e.Analyses).WithOne(re => re.Car).HasForeignKey(e => e.CarId);
        });
```

Scaffolded Create.csthml view doesn't have props that come from `Engine`

```
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OwnerName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OwnerName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OwnerName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        [...]  
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,OwnerName,Make,Model,RegistrationNumber,Vin")] Car car)
```

doesn't expect them.

How should I modify controller and view to also take `Engine` props into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Engine is a complex model,and yo want to bind it,you can try to remove `Bind` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Car car)
```

And then you need to add inputs into view to bind the properties of  Engine:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OwnerName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OwnerName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OwnerName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Engine.Capacity" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Engine.Capacity" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Engine.Capacity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Engine.OilSumpCapacity" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Engine.OilSumpCapacity" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Engine.OilSumpCapacity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        [...]  
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

If you want to bind `EngineType` and `Aspiration`,you can try to add inputs with `asp-for="Engine.EngineType.xxx"` and `asp-for="Engine.Aspiration.xxx"`.

Comment: Thank you, but it's counterintuitive and it kinda works, but why should I remove Bind attribute when I want to bind?

Comment: It looks like you want to bind all the properties of `Car`,so you don't need to use bind attribute to select which properties to bind.If you want to use `Bind` attribute,you can try to use `[Bind("Engine,Id,OwnerName,Make,Model,RegistrationNumber,Vin")]`.